# Value class instantiation?

Tags: scala

```
trait IntWrapper[@specialized(Long, Int) T] extends Any { 
  def value: T
  type I = Integral[T]
  implicit def leFromInt(i: Int)(implicit i2: I): T = i2.fromInt(i)
  implicit def leToInt(t: T)(implicit i2: I): Int = i2.toInt(t)

  def nums(implicit i: I) = {
    import i._
    @tc def inner(remaind: T, acc: List[Int]): List[Int] = quot(remaind, 10) match {
      case that if equiv(0, that) => rem(remaind, 10)::acc
      case that => inner(that, rem(remaind, 10)::acc)
    }
    inner(value, Nil)
  }
}
object Test {
  implicit class intw(val value: Int) extends AnyVal with IntWrapper[Int]
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println{
      3.nums
    }
  }
}
```

Running javap -c Test$ gives

```
public void main(java.lang.String[]);
      Code:
         0: getstatic     #24                 // Field scala/Predef$.MODULE$:Lscala/Predef$;
         3: new           #26                 // class Test$intw
         6: dup           
         7: aload_0       
         8: iconst_3      
         9: invokevirtual #28                 // Method intw:(I)I
        12: invokespecial #31                 // Method Test$intw."<init>":(I)V
        15: getstatic     #36                 // Field scala/math/Numeric$IntIsIntegral$.MODULE$:Lscala/math/Numeric$IntIsIntegral$;
        18: invokevirtual #40                 // Method Test$intw.nums:(Lscala/math/Integral;)Lscala/collection/immutable/List;
        21: invokevirtual #44                 // Method scala/Predef$.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
        24: return
```

Given that

> A value class is actually instantiated when:
>
> a value class is treated as another type. a value class is assigned to
>   an array. doing runtime type tests, such as pattern matching.

Why is intw instantiated?

Answer (score 1):

The `nums` method is not defined in `intw`, but in its parent trait `IntWrapper`, and when you invoke a method from a trait that a value class inherits from initialization is required. This is an instance of "a value class is treated as another type". See the final part of the Introduction and the first part of Allocation Details in [Value Classes and Universal Traits](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html) on the Scala website.

In this particular case, the initialization could be eliminated, but the compiler isn't currently smart enough to do this. It is discused briefly at the end of the [Value Classes proposal](https://docs.google.com/document/d/10TQKgMiJTbVtkdRG53wsLYwWM2MkhtmdV25-NZvLLMA/edit?hl=en_US).